# Angular Momentum Derivation without Vector products - is it possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, vectors

I am trying to prove myself the formula for angular momentum:

$$L = mvr = pr$$

without use of any vectors.

I started by considering the comparison between $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and $E = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2r^2$ and have been left stuck to progress onwards to proving the formula above.

There are no proofs that I can find which involve the angular momentum derivation **without** the use of products of vectors.

Is it possible to prove $L = pr$ without vector products?

Comment: I don't see the point. Space is 3D, not 1D. Besides in 1D, obviously, no rotation is possible.

Comment: @DavidSmith If you're ever trying to do a proof, you need to be very clear about what assumptions/suppositions you are beginning with and what you want to use them to show (what you want to prove). You have not provided us with a starting point (initial suppositions), that is why every one is saying that it's simply a definition. For instance, perhaps you may insist that we begin proving the formula by assuming conservation of energy, or something else.......?

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove a definition.

Angular momentum is defined as
$$\mathbf L=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$$

With what you are using it seems like $\mathbf{r}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf p$, so you can relate the magnitudes $L=rp$, but it is still a definition.

Furthermore, angular momentum is a vector quantity, so trying to "prove" this without using vectors seems to be counterproductive. Unless you worked with each component individually, then I guess you could somewhat say you didn't work with the vectors in their entirety.$^*$

---

$^*$More explicitly we can start with:
$$L_x=yp_z-zp_y$$
$$L_y=zp_x-xp_z$$
$$L_z=xp_y-yp_x$$

So then
$$\begin{align}L^2&=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2\\&=y^2p_z^2+z^2p_y^2-2yzp_yp_z+z^2p_x^2+x^2p_z^2-2xzp_xp_z+x^2p_y^2+y^2p_x^2-2xyp_xp_y\end{align}$$

Since you want to end up with $L=rp$, we can exploit that $\mathbf{r}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf p$ (let's call this intuition rather than using vectors?) Then it must be true that
$$xp_x+yp_y+zp_z=0$$
Or squaring both sides and rearranging
$$x^2p_x^2+y^2p_y^2+z^2p_z^2=-2xyp_xp_y-2yzp_yp_z-2xzp_xp_z$$

Using this we find that
$$\begin{align}L^2&=y^2p_z^2+z^2p_y^2+z^2p_x^2+x^2p_z^2+x^2p_y^2+y^2p_x^2+x^2p_x^2+y^2p_y^2+z^2p_z^2\\&=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2)\\&=r^2p^2\end{align}$$

Therefore
$$L=rp$$

Of course this still pretty much relies on vector products. Angular momentum is defined as a vector product, so there isn't really a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking your question to mean show angular momentum *is conserved*. I'll do this for a single particle in two dimensions in a central potential. The standard way to do this without explicitly using vectors is via the Lagrangian formalism, but I suspect you haven't seen that yet. In any case I'll show you via energy conservation and what you should know about centripetal motion.

There are two directions in this problem. You don't want to use vectors but physically you still need to account for them. There is the velocity in the radial direction $\dot{r}$ and the velocity in the angular direction $r\omega$.

You only wrote the rotational part of the kinetic energy. There is also radial kinetic energy and potential energy $U(r)$
$$E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\frac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2+U(r)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}E=m(\dot{r}{\ddot{r}}+r\dot{r}\omega^2+r^2\omega\dot{\omega})+U'(r)\dot{r}=0$$

after a few steps...
$$\dot{r}(m{\ddot{r}}-mr\omega^2+U'(r))+\omega\frac{d}{dt}(mr^2\omega)=0$$
The first expression in parenthesis involves the force $F=-U'$ and the acceleration, which we know satisfy
$$F=m\ddot{r}+ma_c$$
where the centripetal acceleration $a_c=-r\omega^2$.

So the first term vanishes and from the second term
$$\frac{d}{dt}(mr^2\omega)=0$$
$$$$

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Stevens is correct when he notes that "You can't prove a definition."  But I think that we can actually go further than that in this case.  The definition
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf L=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}
\end{equation}
uses vectors precisely because *direction matters*.  In particular, physics tells use that angular momentum should add as a vector because [*conservation of angular momentum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Conservation_of_angular_momentum) requires it.  If you have two identical discs spinning at the same rates, but in opposite directions, you can bring them together and make them stop spinning entirely without any external torques.  But if you define angular momentum by $L=pr$, you lose the information about directions.  [There are other problems — like the fact that you actually need $\mathbf{r}$ to be *orthogonal to* $\mathbf{p}$ to have nonzero angular momentum — but what I've mentioned here is the most obvious objection.]

So we can definitively answer your question:

> Is it possible to prove $L=pr$ without vector products?

The answer is no, it is not possible because that formula actually contradicts the definition of $\mathbf{L}$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to prove $L = pr$ without vector products?

This equation is the definition of the magnitude of the angular momentum about a point where $r$ is the length of the perpendicular from the point to the line of action of the linear momentum $p$.
The direction of the angular momentum can then be defined using a right-handed set of coordinate axes.

What the vector product does for you is make it possible to write down a concise defining equation for angular momentum $\mathbf L=\mathbf{r'}\times\mathbf{p}$ which contains information about the magnitude and the direction of the angular momentum.

So in theory you do not need to use the vector cross product to find the angular momentum but doing so often makes life a lot easier.

---

A good example of vectors being used to produce concise equations is to compare Maxwell's equation in his [original paper (page 480 onwards)](http://www.bem.fi/library/1865-001.pdf)  and the [modern form of the equations using vector notation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~bruhn/Original-MAXWELL.htm&prev=search).